# ASP.NET Routing to pass query string to the page

Tags: asp.net, query-string, url-routing

I'm using ASP.NET routing to map URLs to some arbitrary number of sections to my site. They will all be handled by the same page, though I want to have different URLs. For example

`http://site.com/blog` for my `blog` section
`http://site.com/mysection` for `mysection` etc.

There can be any number of those sections, but they will all be handled by `Lister.aspx`.
I also have another page that handles the content, named `ContentView.aspx` which shows off content. My route is as follows: (cats is list of categories)

```
cats.ForEach(c =>
        {
            table.Add(new Route(c.ShortName, new PageRouteHandler("~/Lister.aspx?cat=" + c.ID), ));
            table.Add(new Route(c.ShortName + "/{id}", new PageRouteHandler("~/ContentView.aspx")));
            table.Add(new Route(c.ShortName + "/{id}/{title}", new PageRouteHandler("~/ContentView.aspx")));
        });
```

Let's say I have a blog post with ID `123` and title `hello`:
A user can access it by `http://site.com/blog/123/hello`
They can also use just the ID `http://site.com/blog/123`
As you may guess, I want  `http://site.com/blog` to point to the lister page instead of a content viewer, and I also need the category ID to distinguish which category (`blog` or `mycategory` or anything else that was created dynamically) I should display. I'm trying to pass the category ID to the querystring, the lister page is called, but with no query string. Why is this behavior, and how can I send my category ID to the lister page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating your own RouteHandler that implements IRouteHandler which you could then pass a separate parameter to its constructor (the category ID).

Then in the GetHttpHandler you could then pass that ID on to the Page using HttpContext.

Something like:

```
public class CategoryRouteHandler : IRouteHandler 
{
   private string _virtualPath;
   private string _category;

   public CategoryRouteHandler(string virtualPath, string category)
   {
       _virtualPath = virtualPath;
       _category = category;
   }

   public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) 
   {
        var handler = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(
            _virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IDefaultHttpHandler;

        HttpContext.Current.Items["Category"] = _category;

        return handler;
   }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
table.Add(new Route(c.ShortName, new CategoryRouteHandler("~/Lister.aspx", c.ID), ));
```

And from the code of Lister you can access `HttpContext.Current.Items["Category"]`

**Edit**: updated to fix the code, sorry I didn't test it the first time.

Comment: your code contains two errors: what is the base class of CategoryRouteHandler and what does GetHttpHandler method return? I tried to get it working by using PageRouteHandler as base class and returning the current IHttpHandler but could't pass the value to the page.